# Podio REST API attach file incorrect rights to update file

Tags: podio

My goal is to copy an existing file from one item 'A' in app 'B', to item 'X' in app 'Y'.
First PHP API function `PodioFile::copy(file_id)` is used to copy the existing file attached to item 'A' and to get the **file_id** of the copy. Then, after authenticating with app 'Y',

```
PodioFile::attach(obtained_file_id_from_copy, array("ref_type" => "item", "ref_id" => item_x_id)
```

is used to attach the copied file to the item 'X' in app 'Y'.

The problem: When trying to attach the file a **PodioForbiddenError** is given. The response is as follows (error_description is important):

```
{"error_parameters":{},"error_detail":null,"error_propagate":false,"request":{"url":"http:\/\/api.podio.com\/file\/749459918\/attach","query_string":"","method":"POST"},

"error_description":"The app with id 21217623 does not have the right update on file with id 749459918","error":"forbidden"}
```

I haven't found any helpful information regarding this matter, hopefully someone is able to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access other app's data/files using another app's authentication.
You need to authenticate as `app B` to fetch file/data and change the authentication to `app Y` to attach/put file or data.
Otherwise, try using **authenticating as a user** who has access to both the Apps so you don't have to change the authentication each time.

Ref: [Podio authentication](https://developers.podio.com/authentication)